# How to specify Swagger specification extensions via code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to add custom properties into the info section of the swagger.json that gets generated.  I found many articles that talk about how to add the properties in the json by prefixing them with "x-".  (ex: https://swagger.io/specification/#specification-extensions)

But, I cannot find anything that shows how to do this via C# code.  (Currently using .NET 5)

We currently set the standard properties like so:

```
options.SwaggerDoc(Swagger.Version, new OpenApiInfo
{
  Title = "Service Api",
  Version = Swagger.Version,
  Description = "This describes the routes associated with the Service Api."
});
```

Just to test this, I tried extending OpenApiInfo like so:

```
public class CustomInfo : OpenApiInfo
{
  [JsonPropertyName("x-test")]
  public String Test;
}
```

then altering the SwaggerDoc like so:

```
options.SwaggerDoc(Swagger.Version, new CustomInfo
{
  Title = "Service Api",
  Version = Swagger.Version,
  Description = "This describes the routes associated with the Service Api.",
  Test = "New Value"
});
```

This did not work.  How can I add a custom property (specification extension) to the api info?

Comment: Maybe take a look at property extensions ? It's C# 8 or more, but since you are .net-5 you already got that.

Comment: From what I could find, property extensions don't exist in C# just yet.

Answer (score 3):

I found that you can easily add the custom properties (specification extensions) to the `OpenApiInfo`'s Extension property.  You do not need to create your own classes that implement `IOpenApiExtension` for the value of the Dictionary.  The class that came with the Swagger nuget package that I used was `OpenApiString`

```
options.SwaggerDoc(Swagger.Version, new OpenApiInfo
{
  Title = "Service Api",
  Version = Swagger.Version,
  Description = "This describes the routes associated with the Service Api.",
  Extensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>
  {
    { "x-company", new OpenApiString("Company Name") },
    { "x-contact", new OpenApiString("contact@email.com") }
  }
});
```

There are many other ready to use classes like `OpenApiBoolean`, `OpenApiDateTime`, or if you need an object, `OpenApiObject`.  There are many others as well.

Comment: How can I add a specification extension to every single endpoint?